# linker out of memory LNK1102

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker

My colleagues and I have tried to build a project containing several thousand classes , but we're getting a LNK1102 error ( Linker out of memory ) . I've seen several tips on the internet , such as increasing the virtual memory . We tried but this didn't help . We've also seen some as enabling different warning levels when compiling the code . A guy suggested enabling level 4 for warnings .
How could that be done ? Are there other suggestions ?

Comment: Which language are you compiling and which tool version?

Comment: we're building C++ code, using Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Platform Builder .

Comment: Probably best not to tag this "Windows" - that's normally interpreted as the x86/x64 product.

Comment: By "increasing the virtual memory", are you talking about the /3GB flag and friends (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791558.aspx)?

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same problem when compiling plain C:

```
"*LINK : fatal error LNK1102: out of memory*"
```

Solution for me was: delete all *.pdb (DEBUG) files around.
After that, everything was linked without problems. So probably a pdb file was defect in my case - defect in a funny way to cause this linker error.

Comment: Cleaning out the pdb files solved the LNK1102 errors, and seemed to speed up the build slightly!

Answer (score 6):

Project (right click) → Properties → Configuration Properties → Linker → Optimization → References → change to **Keep Unreferenced Data**

Worked on my machine!

Answer (score 1):

If the project is too large, then split it up into several components.

This might also help with maintenance.

Comment: We're preferring to keep that as a last option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this on a windows machine, open up task manager while linking and go to the performance page.
If you see the page file usage increasing until its full, then increase the size of it to at least double your ram.
If the page file is not filling up before it throws the error, then ensure there is enough disk space on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the linker also takes a lot of time to finish. Since you are saying there are thousands of c++ classes, my first thought was to check if there are many inlined class methods.

Try this:

Pick a bunch of classes that are used the most, make all inlined methods non-inline by moving them from the header file to the implementation file. I've experienced drastic changes in linking time. One project we had went from 15 minutes of pure linking to just 30 seconds. This should also affect the memory of the linking process.

Good luck!
//Magnus

Answer (score 1):

If using Visual C++ 6.0, avoid loading workspace from a "subst" drive or "network mapped" drive. Copying the project to "C:\temp\MyProject\" folder, and loading the workspace from this location, made the "LNK1102" error go away for me this time.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had this `fatal error LNK1102: out of memory` error and solved it by [using 64bits compiler and linker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2891057/linker-fatal-error-lnk1102-out-of-memory). You set an environment variable:

```
set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64
```

and then run Visual Studio.

Comment: best answer 4 sure!

Answer (score 0):

Run the 64 bits version of the Linker? Downside: you'll get a amd64 executable.
(Unlike the 32->64 crosscompilation toolset, there is no 64->32 bit toolset)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely monitor the actual memory usage through task manager while linking. Close other programs to increase your available physical memory and set your page file to 4092 mb in size, if possible.

Also, it might help to create a [link repro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/134650). This will allow other people to try to reproduce your link issues on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error while incremental building of a big project in VS 2008. I've just Clean the project, delete all *.ilk, *.dll, *.exe and *.pdb files and built all again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2891057/linker-fatal-error-lnk1102-out-of-memory) a couple of times is to use the 64 bit host compiler tools.

For a CMake-generated project this can be achieved by setting the variable [`CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET.html) to the value `host=x64`, either in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "host=x64")
```

or on the cmake command line add

```
-T host=x64
```

**Note**: this setting only applicable to Visual Studio generators. For any other generators it will cause a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use `clang-cl` as a drop-in replacement. This was the only way I found to work around this issue with VS16 and VS17 on a GitHub-hosted action.

For CMake-based projects provide the `-T ClangCL` argument.
Otherwise, read up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=msvc-170